# How do I install unity-lens-shopping?

Tags: installation, unity, lenses

I am trying to install the unity-lens-shopping app.

I've downloaded unity-lens-shopping-6.8.0. When I ran `./configure` the first time it complained I did not have the valac compiler. I went to the Ubuntu Software Center and installed it from there. This installed version 0.14.2. Then when I ran `./configure` it said it complained **configure: error: Vala 0.16.0 not found**.

I went to "https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Release" and downloaded vala-0.18.0. When I run ./configure in there I get "**configure: error: flex not found but required**". Is there an easier (aka shorter) way to get the lens installed?

Answer (score 0):

Install 12.10 - It has shopping and the music store in the Unity lens.